# Binding class member function to c-function

Tags: c++, templates

Below I have a concept of binding class member function to a global function. The main purpose of this is using C++ for C-style callback function implementation. Can this be done in a better way (for example, without final macro or `typeof`, or using C++0x features)?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename MF> struct mf_wrapper_helper;

template<typename R, typename T>
struct mf_wrapper_helper<R (T::*)()>
{
    template <R (T::*F)()>
    static R wrapper(T *foo) { return (foo->*F)(); }
};

template<typename R, typename T, typename T1>
struct mf_wrapper_helper<R (T::*)(T1)>
{
    template <R (T::*F)(T1)>
    static R wrapper(T *foo, T1 arg1) { return (foo->*F)(arg1); }
};

#define BIND_MF(mf) \
    mf_wrapper_helper<typeof(mf)>::wrapper<mf>


struct Foo
{
    void x() { cout << "Foo::x()" << endl; }
    void x1(int i) { cout << "Foo::x1(" << i << ")" << endl; }
};

int
main()
{
    typedef void (*f_t)(Foo *);
    typedef void (*f1_t)(Foo *, int i);

    Foo foo;

    f_t f_p = BIND_MF(&Foo::x);
    (*f_p)(&foo);

    f1_t f1_p = BIND_MF(&Foo::x1);
    (*f1_p)(&foo, 314);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? If you can use C++0x, just use lambda's that are capture-less, they can be converted to function pointers. Also, why dynamically allocate something in `main`?

Comment: Ignore that `new` - doesn't matter for the question. I use GCC 4.5 and ICC 11.1. Not sure how lambda helps here, since `Lambda functions are function objects of an implementation-dependent type`. Actually, I don't know C++0x well, code example is appreciated.

Comment: Voted to close because this question would **probably** be better-suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @klimkin: Like I said, you could make an in-place lambda and it can be converted to a function pointer. We just need to know if C++0x is an option. "Ignore that new - doesn't matter for the question." Exactly, so why is it there? :) @John: I dunno, maybe if it were an official exchange site, but for now it should go here. (Disregarding I think the code-review site is unnecessary.)

Comment: I think C++0x is an option. To my knowledge, both compiler versions support lambdas at least. Fixed the foo.

Comment: Then in a few hours I'll get back to you with some code. :)

Comment: One point worth making, though not really an answer: The C++0x keyword `decltype` is mostly the same thing as the g++ compiler extension `typeof`.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2935201/196844

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the only technique which will work perfectly is to write a C wrapper function for each member function that you wish to invoke within a C callback; i.e.:

```
extern "C" void Foo_x(Foo *foo)
{
    foo->x();
}

extern "C" void Foo_x1(Foo *foo, int i)
{
    foo->x1(i);
}
```

You could also use lambda expressions of C++0x, which implicitly convert to a pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator. But, keep in mind that the language linkage of the function type is "C++", not "C".

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    void x() { cout << "Foo::x()" << endl; }
    void x1(int i) { cout << "Foo::x1(" << i << ")" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    typedef void (*f_t)(Foo*); // default ("C++") language linkage
    typedef void (*f1_t)(Foo*, int);

    Foo foo;

    Foo_x(&foo);
    Foo_x1(&foo, -10);

    f_t fn = [] (Foo *foo) {
        foo->x();
    };
    fn(&foo);

    f1_t fn1 = [] (Foo *foo, int i) {
        foo->x1(i);
    };
    fn1(&foo, 314);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that Section 5.2.2, Function call, of the C++ Standard states:

> Calling a function through an expression whose function type has a language linkage that is different from the language linkage of the function type of the called function’s definition is undefined.

So the following technically invokes undefined behavior:

```
extern "C" typedef void (*f_t)(Foo*);

int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    f_t fn = [] (Foo *foo) {
        foo->x();
    };
    fn(&foo); // `fn` is a pointer to a function that uses "C++" language linkage,
            // but it is erroneously called through "C" language linkage.

//...
```

**EDIT:** After a bit of experimentation, I came up with the following template functions which return lambdas that call the given member function:

```
template <typename return_t, class base, typename... arg_types>
std::function<return_t (base*, arg_types...)> make_lambda_to_call_member_function(return_t (base::*mem_fn)(arg_types...)) 
{
    return [mem_fn] (base *o, arg_types... args) -> return_t {
        (o->*mem_fn)(args...);
    };
}

template <typename return_t, class base, typename... arg_types>
std::function<return_t (const base*, arg_types...)> make_lambda_to_call_member_function(return_t (base::*cmem_fn)(arg_types...) const) 
{
    return [cmem_fn] (const base *o, arg_types... args) -> return_t {
        (o->*cmem_fn)(args...);
    };
}
```

If `Foo` is defined as:

```
struct Foo
{
    void x() { cout << "Foo::x()" << endl; }
    void x1(int i) { cout << "Foo::x1(" << i << ")" << endl; }
    void cx1(float f) const { cout << "Foo::cx1(" << f << ")" << endl; }
};
```

Then you use the template `make_lambda_to_call_member_function` like:

```
auto fn = make_lambda_to_call_member_function(&Foo::x);
fn(&foo);

auto fn1 = make_lambda_to_call_member_function(&Foo::x1);
fn1(&foo, 314);

auto fn2 = make_lambda_to_call_member_function(&Foo::cx1);
fn2(&foo, 44.832f);
```

Note, however, that the returned lambda objects will not implicitly convert to a function pointer because the lambda expression uses a lambda-capture.

The latest draft of C++0x, n3225, states:

> The closure type for a *lambda-expression* with no *lambda-capture* has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type's function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type's function call operator.

The following is illegal:

```
void (*fn5)(Foo*) = make_lambda_to_call_member_function(&Foo::x);
```

Comment: It's a good point about linkage type. I see a problem with using lambda - all argument types should be fully listed. With template version all types are calculated with compiler. Is it possible to make a template of lambda function, which will take member function as parameter?

Comment: @klimkin: I updated my answer with a lot more information. To answer your question, yes it's possible to write a template function that returns a lambda object that invokes a given member function, but that lambda object can no longer be converted to a function pointer.