# EnumChildWindows and lambda

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, mingw

When I try to compile the following on MinGW 4.6.2

```
EnumChildWindows(hwnd, [](HWND, LPARAM) -> BOOL { return TRUE; }, 0);
```

I get

```
error: cannot convert '<lambda(HWND, LPARAM)>'
to 'ENUMWINDOWSPROC {aka int (*)(HWND__*,long int)}'
for argument '2' to 'BOOL EnumChildWindows(HWND, ENUMWINDOWSPROC, LPARAM)'
```

Am I declaring the lambda incorrectly, or is this simply not going to work? The MS definition of the callback is

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(
  __in  HWND hwnd,
  __in  LPARAM lParam
);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Is the calling convention causing the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935201/will-c0x-support-stdcall-or-extern-c-capture-nothing-lambdas is related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> BOOL **CALLBACK** EnumChildProc(...)

That's the problem, the CALLBACK macro applies the __stdcall attribute to the function to change the calling convention from the default setting.  Which is __cdecl in most programs.  You cannot control the calling convention for your lambda, other than by changing the global setting (/Gz compile option).  That can have a lot more side-effects than you'd care about, give up on this lamda.

Not a problem in 64-bit code btw.

Comment: @luksy : Also note that VC++11 handles this for you implicitly (i.e., It Just Works).