# Use C++11 lambdas as callbacks in GObject library

Tags: c++11, lambda, gobject

C++11 lambdas that does not capture anything can be stored in a function pointer. One just need to ensure that lambda accepts and returns the same parameters as the function pointer.

In [GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Closures.html#G-CALLBACK%3aCAPS) library all callbacks has type `void(*GCallback) (void)`. This definition does not anyhow affect signature of the callback though:

> The type used for callback functions in structure definitions and
>   function signatures. This doesn't mean that all callback functions
>   must take no parameters and return void. The required signature of a
>   callback function is determined by the context in which is used (e.g.
>   the signal to which it is connected). Use G_CALLBACK() to cast the
>   callback function to a GCallback.

In other words, one can pass function like this:

```
int my_function(int a, char b) {}
```

by casting its type (that's what G_CALLBACK do):

```
do_something(G_CALLBACK(my_function));
```

Unfortunately typecasting does not work with C++11 lambdas:

```
do_something(G_CALLBACK([](int a, char b) -> int {...});
// Cannot cast from type lambda to pointer type GCallback
```

Is it possible to use C++ lambdas of arbitrary type in place of GCallback?

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify, I know that lambda can be casted to a function pointer if their signatures match. My question is in another dimension.

The ISO C standard guarantees that function can be casted forth and back without loosing any precision. In other words one the following expression is valid:

```
int f(int a){...}

void (*void_f)() = (void (*)())f;
int (*restored_f)(int) = (int (*)(int))void_f;
restored_f(10);
```

My question is whether the following expression is also valid according to C++11:

```
int (*f)(int) = [](int a) -> int {};
void (*void_f)() = (void (*)())f;
int (*restored_f)(int) = (int (*)(int))void_f;
restored_f(10);
```

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but you may try to store the lambda as a variable (`auto fun = [](...){...};`) and then do an explicit cast in the `do_something` call (`do_something(reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(fun));`). Since I haven't tried it, I have no idea if it will work or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657011/is-it-safe-to-cast-a-lambda-function-to-a-function-pointer

Comment: @icepack this question is not about how to use lambdas in place of function pointers. It's about how (if possible) to use lambda of arbitrary type in place of GCallback.

Comment: @Kentzo I understand that. If you look closely into that answer, you'll see that it's not always possible to interchange lambdas for C pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas without a capture [are implicitly convertible](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3052.html) to a pointer to a function by the standard. Though not all compilers support this feature at the moment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2935230/261217).

Then you can explicitly cast a function pointer to `GCallback`.

Comment: Please see update of my question. Whether the second expression is valid under C++11? If so, could you point to the standard?

Comment: I see no problem in this conversion, lambda function is just a method of anonymous class. It exists just like the normal function. I cannot point to the standard though, sorry, I'm too lazy :)

Answer (score 2):

The following code compiles and works for me (MSVC 2013):

```
auto lambdaFunc = [](int a, char b) -> int { return 0; };

typedef int (*LambdaType)(int, char);

GCallback fnTest1 = G_CALLBACK((LambdaType)lambdaFunc);
GCallback fnTest2 = G_CALLBACK((LambdaType) [](int a, char b) -> int { return 0; });

do_something(fnTest1);
do_something(fnTest2);
do_something(G_CALLBACK((LambdaType)lambdaFunc));
```